# BlockingCollection<T>.GetConsumingEnumerable() blocking on an additional condition

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, ienumerable, blockingcollection

Is it possible to have a `BlockingCollection<T>` (`JobQueue` in my example) block execution on both the `GetConsumingEnumerable()` stream AND on some other criteria?

I have the condition `availableSlots > 0` which only allows items to be consumed when there are available slots.  The problem is that the foreach indefinitely loops when there are items in the collection but the condition is false.

Can I not get the collection to block on `availableSlots > 0` as well?

```
foreach (var job in JobQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    if(availableSlots > 0)
    {
        JobHandler jobHandler = job;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            ExecuteJob(jobHandler);
        });
    }
}
```

Perhaps I am using this collection incorrectly.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: `if(availableSlots > 0)` What is this doing? You're ignoring the elements you pulled out from collection

Comment: Based on your scenario it would be better to move condition checking outside of the loop. Don't consume items if you don't need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to block while the value is 0, you will need additional synchronization for this. I think the right solution for you is [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx), because it does exactly what you need: waiting while its value is 0.

With that, the code would look something like:

```
SemaphoreSlim slotsSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(…);

…

foreach (var job in JobQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    slotsSemaphore.Wait();

    JobHandler jobHandler = job;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            ExecuteJob(jobHandler);
        }
        finally
        {
            slotsSemaphore.Release();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Am confused with this approach, How does this work? when we set `initialCount` to `0` and call `Wait()` it blocks indefinitely right? How'll we release it?

Comment: When you create `SemaphoreSlim`, you usually set it to some non-zero value. `Wait()` then decreases the value (after wait, if it can't do it right away) and `Release()` increases the value.

Comment: You don't need additional synchronization for blocking while the count is 0.  Hence the name "BlockingCollection" - the collection blocks on Take(), TryTake(), and GetConsumingEnumerable() when empty.  This class was written specifically so that you don't need to implement blocking/signalling yourself.

Comment: @DaveBlack Have you read the question? The "value" in my answer is not the count of items in the collection, it's not some other value, which is what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best way, but putting my option forward.

Why not just wait until it is true?

```
while (availableSlots <= 0)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);//arbitary sleep
}

JobHandler jobHandler = job;
...
```

or use `SpinWait`

```
SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => availableSlots > 0);

JobHandler jobHandler = job;
...
```

Third option is to use `ManualResetEvent` or `AutoResetEvent`

```
signal.Waitone();

JobHandler jobHandler = job;
...
```

And set the `signal` when you change the value of `availableSlots`.

Comment: @svick Which one you say busy wait? Both are yielding its time slices to another thread. Not sure what you mean busy wait

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought about using the Thread.Sleep() approach, but I was hoping to move away from polling.  Maybe I should scrap foreaching `GetConsumingEnumerable()` and rather somehow manually `Take` and `TryTake` off the collection?

Comment: Both are busy waiting, they are unnecessarily checking the condition over and over.

Comment: @svick Point taken, updated my answer with Signaling. Is that optimimal?

Comment: That's upto you, you can stick with `GetConsumingEnumerable` or use while loop, any.. Nothing stops you :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yeah, that's much better.

Comment: @Downvoter care to comment, Am ready to revise my answer based on your comment